# Cannot write to additional hard drives in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, permissions, hard-drive

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, and no dual-boot.

Ubuntu is installed on my SSD, but I also have two 2TB drives (connected via SATA to my motherboard) for my additional storage. The HDDs are formatted as ext4 and can be mounted & read (maybe, if there was something on them) but that is it. I cannot write anything to either of them & cannot create symbolic links.

I can't drag folders from home to the mounted HDD via the file explorer. I also cannot create new directories in the mounted HDD via the file explorer. When I check the permissions of the mounted HDD (via right-click menu **Properties > Permissions**), it says

> The permissions of 'drivename' could not be determined.

This question has surely been asked before, but when I try those solutions, I get no help.

Does anyone have any solution?